# Как сделать плавную стерку на краях svg

Tags: html, css, svg

как сделать плавное стирание у линии на концах как на скрине с помощью svg?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось только вот так, но концы не затерты на концах:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#45678B"  d="M-0.000,83.000 C-0.000,83.000 17.403,22.656 49.000,6.000 C81.878,-11.331 129.000,15.000 129.000,15.000 "/>

    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#45678B" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#45678B"/>
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#45678B"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#45678B" stop-opacity="0" />
    </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <path d="M-0.000,83.000 C-0.000,83.000 17.403,22.656 49.000,6.000 C81.878,-11.331 129.000,15.000 129.000,15.000 " stroke="url(#grad1)" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```